# Cannot install ggplot with conda-forge

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I am trying to install ggplot with conda-forge. But it is showing some certain error. Details error message is given below.

```
(base) C:\Users\ASUS>conda install -c conda-forge ggplot=0.11.5
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
```

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - ggplot=0.11.5 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

Please help me with any solution.

Comment: You shouldn't use the base environment for development. Create a new, separate environment for each project/application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an alternative of `ggplot`, which contains all `ggplot` function. It's `plotnine`. 
To install `plotnine`

```
# Using pip
$ pip install plotnine         # 1. should be sufficient for most
$ pip install 'plotnine[all]'  # 2. includes extra/optional packages

# Or using conda
$ conda install -c conda-forge plotnine
```

For usage guideline please visit https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The development of yhat's ggplot python port [stopped in 2016](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy). It seems that it is only compatible with `pandas<0.22` which predates python 3.7 and is thus not available for python-3.7 on conda-forge.

The easiest way to use it is to install it into an environment with a python3.6 interpreter.